# crosstool-ng download toolchain component tarball 'automake' failed

Tags: crosstool-ng

I tried to `ct-ng build` the rpi3 config with Docker in MacOSX.

The version of crosstool-ng is 1.24.0

And there are error messages:

```sh
[INFO ]  Performing some trivial sanity checks
[INFO ]  Build started 20200508.202746
[INFO ]  Building environment variables
[EXTRA]  Preparing working directories
[EXTRA]  Installing user-supplied crosstool-NG configuration
[EXTRA]  =================================================================
[EXTRA]  Dumping internal crosstool-NG configuration
[EXTRA]    Building a toolchain for:
[EXTRA]      build  = x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
[EXTRA]      host   = x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
[EXTRA]      target = armv8-rpi3ubuntu-linux-gnueabihf
[EXTRA]  Dumping internal crosstool-NG configuration: done in 0.35s (at 00:04)
[INFO ]  =================================================================
[INFO ]  Retrieving needed toolchain components' tarballs
[ERROR]    automake: download failed
[ERROR]
[ERROR]  >>
[ERROR]  >>  Build failed in step 'Retrieving needed toolchain components' tarballs'
[ERROR]  >>        called in step '(top-level)'
[ERROR]  >>
[ERROR]  >>  Error happened in: CT_Abort[scripts/functions@487]
[ERROR]  >>        called from: CT_DoFetch[scripts/functions@2103]
[ERROR]  >>        called from: CT_PackageRun[scripts/functions@2063]
[ERROR]  >>        called from: CT_Fetch[scripts/functions@2174]
[ERROR]  >>        called from: do_companion_tools_automake_get[scripts/build/companion_tools/300-automake.sh@5]
[ERROR]  >>        called from: do_companion_tools_get[scripts/build/companion_tools.sh@21]
[ERROR]  >>        called from: main[scripts/crosstool-NG.sh@646]
[ERROR]  >>
[ERROR]  >>  For more info on this error, look at the file: 'build.log'
[ERROR]  >>  There is a list of known issues, some with workarounds, in:
[ERROR]  >>      https://crosstool-ng.github.io/docs/known-issues/
[ERROR]  >>
[ERROR]  >>  If you feel this is a bug in crosstool-NG, report it at:
[ERROR]  >>      https://github.com/crosstool-ng/crosstool-ng/issues/
[ERROR]  >>
[ERROR]  >>  Make sure your report includes all the information pertinent to this issue.
[ERROR]  >>  Read the bug reporting guidelines here:
[ERROR]  >>      http://crosstool-ng.github.io/support/
[ERROR]
[ERROR]  (elapsed: 0:02.58)
[00:04] / /opt/crosstool-ng/bin/ct-ng:261: recipe for target 'build' failed
make: *** [build] Error 1
```

I checked the packages file in source of crosstool-ng `crosstool-ng-1.24.0/packages/automake/`

In **package.desc**:

```
repository='git https://git.savannah.gnu.org/git/automake.git'
bootstrap='./bootstrap'
mirrors='$(CT_Mirrors GNU automake)'
relevantpattern='1.*|.'
archive_formats='.tar.xz .tar.gz'
signature_format='packed/.sig'
```

Is it something wrong with the download url?
How is "download tarball" purpose?
Is it possible use tarball locally that I download it myself?

Thanks for your patience.